# sort a list in an ascending order python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list

```
keys = [u'3_sd', u'14_sd', u'16_sd', u'13_sd', u'4_sd', u'18_sd', u'22_sd', u'1_sd', u'6_sd', u'7_sd', u'15_sd', u'21_sd', u'19_sd', u'10_sd', u'2_sd', u'17_sd', u'8_sd', u'11_sd', u'9_sd', u'12_sd', u'5_sd', u'20_sd']
```

when i sort it like keys.sort() the result was

```
[u'10_sd',u'11_sd',u'12_sd',u'13_sd',u'14_sd',u'15_sd',u'16_sd',u'17_sd',u'18_sd',u'19_sd',u'1_sd',u'20_sd',u'21_sd',u'22_sd',u'2_sd',u'3_sd',u'4_sd',u'5_sd',u'6_sd',u'7_sd',u'8_sd',u'9_sd']
```

But i need them to sort in numerical ascending order like

```
[u'1_sd',u'2_sd',u'3_sd',u'4_sd',u'5_sd',u'6_sd'.......]
```

I have seen some other ways on google `sorted(keys, key=int)`, which was not working in my case since the elements in the list are strings, so is there a way to sort them in ascending order without manipulating the data in list ?

Comment: You will have to convert the appropriate part to integer, e.g. `int(item.split('_', 1)[0])`, and use that as the key.

Comment: You are dealing with strings, and python will sort them literally. If you want to sort based on first digit you need to split the string and convert the digit to integer. `sorted(keys, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0]))`

Comment: you said it, they are strings so they will be sorted like that unless you extract the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a sufficiently complex `key`.

```
key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0])
```